# RMI connection in javafx standalone application

Tags: java, javafx, rmi

I have the following problem with my javafx application: 
I'm using RMI to connect client app to server, and everything goes fine, until I run application in web browser or standalone mode. In this case, RMI doesn't work properly, but don't throw any exceptions. I cant send any message to server. Problem disappears when I run program in IDE or by clicking on jar file.

I think, that it can be connected with some browser privileges, and application launched in that context probably doesn't have access to network adapter.

Any ideas how to fix that?

EDIT: There was an exception that was invisible for me: java.net.SocketPermission. So as I thought, access to socked is denied. What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned applet can only connect to the host it was loaded from. So, either change your topology or [sign the applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH).